# Javascript: get object value from Object

Tags: javascript

I have a JS Array like:

```
[
 {name: 'Rajat', messages: [{id: 1,message: 'Hello'},{id: 3,message: 'Hello 2'}]},
 {name: 'Himesh', messages: [{id: 2,message: 'Hello'}]},
 {name: 'David', messages: [{id: 4,message: 'Hello'}]}
]
```

It contains chat messages for each contact.How can I get all `messages` related to any one user like `Rajat` based on `name` field?

Comment: Not clear. What you're trying to do? What's your expected result?

Comment: @zulhfreelancer: i want to iterate over `messages` dataset pertaining to 'Rajat' and display them as chat messages

Comment: please be a bit more elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, please see my answer. Accept the answer if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array=  [
 {name: 'Rajat', messages: [{id: 1,message: 'Hello'},{id: 3,message:'Hello 2'}]},
 {name: 'Himesh', messages: [{id: 2,message: 'Hello'}]},
 {name: 'David', messages: [{id: 4,message: 'Hello'}]}
]

 var filteredArray= array.filter(function(value)
  {
    if(value.name === 'Rajat')
     { 
       return true;
     }
     else
      return false;
   })


 return filteredArray[0].messages;
```

Comment: `array.filter(function(e) { return e.name === 'Rajat'; })[0].messages`

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/gaxalupuka/edit?html,js,output (click `Run with JS` button first)

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="showRajatMessages()">Show Rajat Messages</button>
  <ul id="result"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**:

```
var data = [
             {name: 'Rajat',
              messages: [
                          {id: 1, message: 'Hello'},
                          {id: 3, message: 'Hello 2'}
                        ]
             },
             {name: 'Himesh',
              messages: [
                          {id: 2,message: 'Hello'}
                        ]
             },
             {name: 'David',
              messages: [
                          {id: 4,message: 'Hello'}
                        ]
             },
              {name: 'Rajat',
              messages: [
                          {id: 1, message: 'Hello 3'},
                          {id: 3, message: 'Hello 4'}
                        ]
             }
            ];


function showRajatMessages() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if(data[i].name == "Rajat"){
      showMessages(i);
    } else {
      continue; // skip
    }
  }
}

function showMessages(i) {
  console.log(i);
  var messages = data[i].messages;
  for (j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
   $("#result").append("<li>" + messages[j].message + "</li>"); 
  }
}
```

**Explanation**:

First, we listen for the button click. This button click will run `showRajatMessages()` function.

Inside `showRajatMessages()` function, we loop thru the data. If the node has `name` that equal to `Rajat`, we're going to call `showMessages()` function and pass the object position inside the `data` array as `i`.

Inside the `showMessages()` function, we have access to the `i` that just passed from the `showRajatMessages()` function.

So inside here, we find the right object from the `data` array and grab the `messages` key.

And for each item inside the `messages` key, we'll add the `message` as `<li>` and push the `<li>` into the `<ul>` with id name `result` inside the HTML using jQuery `.append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [{
    name: 'Rajat',
    messages: [{
        id: 1,
        message: 'Hello'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        message: 'Hello 2'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Himesh',
    messages: [{
        id: 2,
        message: 'Hello'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'David',
    messages: [{
        id: 4,
        message: 'Hello'
    }]
}];

console.log(data);

var ary = data.map(function(v) {
    if (v.name === 'Rajat') {
        return v.messages.map(function(m) {
            return m.message;
        });
    }
});

ary = [].concat.apply([], ary);

for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    if (typeof ary[i] === 'undefined') {
        ary.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}

console.log(ary);
```

Output:

```
["Hello", "Hello 2"]
```

If you use jquery or lodash, we can shorten this code a bit more.